# Change date in all rows of a DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, python-3.7

I have sample DataFrame:
I would like to replace all the dates with '2012-04-28'

```
In[101]: sample_df
Out[398]: 
  Var       dates
0   A  2012-04-22
1   B  2012-04-22
2   C  2012-04-22
3   D  2012-04-22
```

I have tried the following and it gives me an error:

```
In[102]: sample_df.date.replace('2012-04-22','2012-04-28',inplace=True)

C:\Users\WorkStation\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:6746: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  self._update_inplace(new_data)
```

Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps.

```
df['Dates']=df.Dates.astype(str).replace('2012-04-22','2012-04-28')
```

Comment: I get the following result when I run this...

`
abc.date.replace('2012-04-22' , '2012-04-28')
Out[421]: 
4718   2012-04-22
4719   2012-04-22
4720   2012-04-22
4721   2012-04-22
4722   2012-04-22
   
6347   2012-04-22
6348   2012-04-22
6349   2012-04-22
6350   2012-04-22
6351   2012-04-22
Name: date, Length: 1473, dtype: datetime64[ns]
`

Comment: for some reason it returns to me the original date back again.

Comment: I think your dates column is a datetime object. You first need to convert it into string.
df['Dates']=df.Dates.astype(str).replace('2012-04-22','2012-04-28')
#convert back to datetime
df['Dates']= pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'])

Comment: Damn.... 
@abigya
your the GOD!.
Convert to STR and then changes....

Comment: Happy to help :) @JohnDoe

Answer (score 0):

```
sample_df.loc[sample_df['dates'].eq('2012-04-22'), 'dates'] = '2012-04-28'
```

This should work.

Comment: `sample_df.loc[sample_df['date'].eq('2012-04-22'), 'date'] = '2012-04-28'


C:\Users\WorkStation\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:966: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  self.obj[item] = s`

Answer (score 0):

even easier.  You can assign a value and it will apply to all the column.

```
sample_df.dates = '2012-04-28'
```

Also: In your example your dataframe column shows "dates" with an S. But in your code example you have "date" singular.